# Getting a value error for Linear Regression model

Tags: python, pandas, machine-learning, linear-regression, kaggle

I am trying to work through Kaggle's Titanic competition.  While trying to apply the Linear Regression model to my code and checking its accuracy score, I get the following error on Pycharm:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Users/security/Downloads/AP/Titanic-Kaggle/TItanic-Kaggle.py", line 27, in <module>
    accuracy = linReg.score(x_text, y_test)
  File "C:\Users\security\Anaconda3\envs\TItanic-Kaggle.py\lib\site-packages\sklearn\base.py", line 330, in score
    return r2_score(y, self.predict(X), sample_weight=sample_weight,
  File "C:\Users\security\Anaconda3\envs\TItanic-Kaggle.py\lib\site-packages\sklearn\linear_model\base.py", line 213, in predict
    return self._decision_function(X)
  File "C:\Users\security\Anaconda3\envs\TItanic-Kaggle.py\lib\site-packages\sklearn\linear_model\base.py", line 196, in _decision_function
    X = check_array(X, accept_sparse=['csr', 'csc', 'coo'])
  File "C:\Users\security\Anaconda3\envs\TItanic-Kaggle.py\lib\site-packages\sklearn\utils\validation.py", line 582, in check_array
    context))
ValueError: Found array with 0 sample(s) (shape=(0, 4)) while a minimum of 1 is required.
```

This is my code so far:

```
import pandas as pd
from sklearn.linear_model import LinearRegression

train = pd.read_csv("https://raw.githubusercontent.com/oo92/Titanic-Kaggle/master/train.csv")
test = pd.read_csv("https://raw.githubusercontent.com/oo92/Titanic-Kaggle/master/test.csv")

train['Sex'].replace(['female', 'male'], [0, 1])
train['Embarked'].replace(['C', 'Q', 'S'], [1, 2, 3])

linReg = LinearRegression()

# Fill missing values in Age feature with each sex’s median value of Age
train['Age'].fillna(train.groupby('Sex')['Age'].transform("median"), inplace=True)

data = train[['Pclass', 'SibSp', 'Parch', 'Fare', 'Age']]

# Splitting the dataset that contains the missing values and no missing values as test and train respectively.
x_train = data[data['Age'].notnull()].drop(columns='Age')
y_train = data[data['Age'].notnull()]['Age']
x_text = data[data['Age'].isnull()].drop(columns='Age')
y_test = data[data['Age'].isnull()]['Age']

# Training the machine learning algorithm
linReg.fit(x_train, y_train)

# Checking the accuracy score of the model
accuracy = linReg.score(x_text, y_test)
print(accuracy*100, '%')
```

Comment: There is no `NaN` in `data['Age']`, making `data[data['Age'].isnull()]` an empty dataset. The error is complaining that your `x_text` is empty :)

Comment: Shoot, you're right.  How can I readjust this code?  I am checking the accuracy based on `x_test` and `y_test`?

Comment: indeed, `data[data['Age'].isnull()]` returns empty dataframe.

Comment: What were you trying to achieve by getting entries with `data...isnull()`?

Comment: @AndrosAdrianopolos Question here is: how do you want to divide the train and test datasets? My suggestion is to use `sklearn.model_selection.train_test_split` to create a baseline :)

Comment: @Chris I've never used that before.  How would I apply that to my code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this replacement and it will work:

```
x_text = data[data['Age'] != None].drop(columns='Age')
y_test = data[data['Age'] != None]['Age']
```

This will help.